# how to reboot multiple computer using bash loop from the txt file

Tags: linux, bash, remote, shutdown

can anyone knows how to reboot computer in just one line code of bash (by looping itself). The details will be get from the text file which are the IP Address of each computer. When the script gets the IP address of the computer it will go in and reboot it. HOw can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1# Using for loop**

```
for host in $(< inputfile.txt );
do 

    ssh $host shutdown -r now 

done
```

**Option 2# Using xargs**

```
xargs -n1 -I{} echo ssh {} shutdown -r now  < inputfile.txt
```

Note: You need [SSH Password less login](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) or it will ask password for each host which is listed in inputfile

Comment: don't you need root access for shutdown?

Comment: I have given just example for the what he wants to achieve, now its up to you that you use `sudo`  or  root user.

Comment: Just to give you the next directives: `sudo` usually requires a password. You have to disable the password input for the specified ssh user via `visudo`. Better disable password login anyway in ssh conf file and stick to a id file...

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that :D and `NOPASSWD` option. sometime its bad to do spoon feeding.

Comment: no problem. I am also still learning. :-)

Comment: I mean I don't like to spoon feeding at every details, I answered what he want not all. between after 10 years working in Linux, how I can not aware of that option.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for SERVER in `cat servers.lst`
do
 ssh -tttq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no -o ConnectTimeout=5  $SERVER "sudo su -c 'uname -n;uptime;reboot' "
done
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about what this does and how it works?